# How to call event when right click and select value from gridview cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, right-click

I want to call event when right click then select value in gridview cell.

Is it possible to achieve this?

When right click the cell it will show one popup it contains some value using jquery I achieved this

If I select some value it will be placed in that cell that time I want to call event

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: then search for jQuery plugins

Answer (score 0):

If it happens when you click on Q1, then you could add onclick attribute to the popup item when you are populating it. Then you can use that event to do the work you need.

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        writer.AddAttribute("onclick", "YourFunction()")
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I want to call stored procedure in onclick event..Is it possible? and AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) is not there

Comment: Make a postback to the page with the Yourfunction, for example function Yourfunction(){var eventargs="Stored"; __doPostBack(this,eventargs)}, then on the server side you can use the pageload event to check if var argument= Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; contains  "Stored" and if yes, do what you need to do

Comment: Like if(argument[0]=="Strored"){//TODO}

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Add this
            dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]; 
            // Can leave these here - doesn't hurt
            dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true; 
            dataGrid.Focus();
        }

    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765616/1428854

or

[Right click to select a row in a Datagridview and show a menu to delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035144/right-click-to-select-a-row-in-a-datagridview-and-show-a-menu-to-delete-it)